# A rod of charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

Say you have a *finite* rod of conducting charge. The field from one side of the rod looks like Figure 1:

[image]

At the centre of the sheet, the field lines are straight because of symmetry. (for an infinitesimal length of of the rod) (See Figure 2). Therefore no matter how far you move away at the rod, the field lines at the centre never diverge. Therefore the field is always constant at the centre of the rod. (Kind of how the field is always constant for an infinite rod everywhere, since everywhere is the centre)

However, if you place a point charge *at the centre* and use Coloumb's Law to calculate the force acting on it, the further away you move it from the rod, the weaker the force gets. Why?

### **Note that I'm talking about placing the point charge *at the centre.* I understand why the force becomes weaker for points other than the centre (since the lines diverge). I'm specifically talking bout the center.**

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Sorry, I just realized my diagram of the field lines are wrong (Figure 1). The field lines should   have positive concavity, not negative. The question is till valid though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that the conductor has a dielectricity constant of $\varepsilon_{\rm rel}=1$. (This assumption is not too bad.) The charge in the rod collects as surface charge $\sigma>0$ at its surface $\Sigma\subset \mathbb{R}^3$. We assume furthermore, that the surface is smooth such that $\sigma$ is bounded, i.e., no sharp edges with line charges just to simplify the following considerations. (The same would work with line charges as well.)

We put the origin of coordinates at our observation point and calculate the E-field there:
$$
\vec{E} = -\frac1{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int_{\vec{r}\in\Sigma} \frac{\vec{r}\sigma(\vec{r})d A}{r^3}.
$$
Thereby, $r=|\vec{r}|$.

We can calculate an upper bound of the absolute value $E$ of the field strength:
$$
E \leq \frac1{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\int_{\Sigma}\frac{\max(\sigma)d A}{r^2}\leq \frac{\max_{r\in A}(\sigma) A}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 \min_{r\in A}(r^2)}
$$
For a large distance $R$ of the bar from the origin we have $r\approx R$. Furthermore let us define $\hat{\sigma}:=\max_{r\in A}(\sigma)$. Then we have essentially the upper bound
$$
E\leq \frac{\hat{\sigma} A}{4\pi\varepsilon_0 R^2}
$$
As you see the $E$-field decays at least like $1/R^2$. Actually, the rod electrically looks like a point charge from far away. The orientation of the bar is not relevant for this consideration.

Thus, the radial components of the E-field and the D-field are not constant in the symmetry plane.

Note, that there is a better calculation of the E-field based on the space angle which the observer sees of the charged surface. Here, the estimation is just kept simple.

Note also that the surface charge is arranged such that the interior of the rod keeps field-free. But, that does not matter for the above considerations. The formulae remain valid under the assumption $\varepsilon_{\rm rel}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Saying that the field lines are straight in the center of the rod is only an approximation when you are very close to the rod. As you start to move away the lines do diverge. You can actually see this in your Figure 1. As you have it drawn, the lines (even in the center) begin to move away from each other as you move further from the rod. It is only when you are very close to the rod that they look straight, signifying a "virtually" constant field.

So, therefore, when you place a point charge in the centre of the rod yet very far away, there will be less field lines going through it (meaning weaker field and, in turn, weaker force).

EDIT: Right at the centre there will be a *single* field line that does not diverge. On either side of this field line, the lines *will* diverge, however. Even if we move a fraction of a femptometer to the right or left of perfect center, the field lines will diverge at that point if you move far enough away from the rod. So yes, at the *perfect* center of the rod there is technically a field line that moves straight upward, but on either side of this single line, this is no longer the case. This means that even in the center, as we move further from the rod, the density of field lines is getting smaller, meaning the magnitude of the field is getting smaller.

Comment: But right at the centre, the lines *don't* diverge. There exactly straight so they can't diverge. So for a point charge, placed at the centre, it shouldn't matter right?

Comment: I answered this question in an edit. Does this help to clarify at all?

Comment: Thanks, but a point charge has an infinitesimal width (the same with as a line). So the field that would be applied on it would *only* be that one single straight field line. And since the field on it that doesn't diverge the force should remain constant. I get that if you move an very small distance, away from the centre the lines diverge, but the whole *point* charge is at the centre.

Comment: Correct, a point charge is infinitesimal, however, when talking about electric field strength at a point, we aren't talking about the amount of lines going through the charge. You can have a field at a point regardless if there is a charge there or not. So the field strength is independent of the size of the charge. The field strength is seen visually as how far apart the field lines are. So that would mean if the next field line is very close to the center line, the field is strong. If it is far away, however, it is weak.

Comment: I believe you are thinking of the field line going through the charge and interpreting it in terms of flux instead of field. Flux is essentially a measure of how many field lines pass through a given area. Therefore, if more lines go through a certain area, then the flux gets larger. When talking about field, the area doesn't matter. The field at the infinitesimal point has a strength characterized by how far apart the field lines are. Meaning you can't deduce the strength of the field by only looking at the centre line. You must zoom out a bit and look at the distance between adjacent lines.